# Subreport is getting truncated on Active Report

Tags: c#, activereports

When I am running the report and if subreport has more than 1-page data then it is showing data on the first page only and truncate all remaining data. I have used **BandedList** for the report.

PFA
[image]

I have 20 more Fields which are not showing on next page.

> UPDATE  (12/07/2017)

I am using RDL report. I have attached screen shot

[image]

**CompletedOpsSubReportPortrait.rdlx** is my subreport.

Comment: Have you placed the Subreport inside BandedList or does the Subreport contain the BandedList? Can you share your report files?

Comment: Also, are you using a Page report or RDL report?  there is a slight difference between the two types of reports that might affect the overflow behavior.

Comment: @GrapeCityTeam I am using RDL report and inside RDL report I am using rdlx Subreport and Subreport is inside BandedList